# How to fix shutdown/reboot problem on Ubuntu 16.04 server edition?

Tags: 16.04, shutdown, reboot

has anyone experienced shutdown/reboot issues? I tried shutting down/rebooting but I get the message like "Cannot reached shutdown.target/reboot.target"

I looked at /var/log/syslog and nothing shows up. I also tried "systemctl status xxxxx" (can't remember the exact command) and it's blank too.

I did a net search and the problem seems common but I haven't seen any fixes/workarounds (other than manually unplugging) yet!

Thanks

ps. I upgraded the installation via "apt-get upgrade" and "apt-get dist-upgrade" after first boot and then I restarted the machine.

Comment: Have you tried running "which shutdown"